# Page loading as run(); after upgrading ubuntu to 16.04.2

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, mediawiki

I use mediawiki to run a small internal wiki page on an Ubuntu server. I upgraded the Ubuntu to 16.04.2 and now when I try to load my wiki page, it just says run();

I am assuming this is something to do with the apache2, but I will be honest in saying that I am not super familiar with Linux command line. Most of what I have done has been over many hours and lots of google.

Any help in this would be great, I'm hoping it is just something stupid. I checked the LocalSettings.php for my mediawiki and nothing seems to have changed on that end of the deal.

Comment: Consider posting this question to the Super User community - Stack Overflow is intended for programming related questions

Comment: This is missing a lot of information: was MW installed as a package and therefore upgraded during the install? Which version?

Comment: Oh, most important: does it work if you disable JS?